# Foundation 6 Abide not working with Ajax / Dynamic Html

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, zurb-foundation, abide

This problem is really annoying me.

In this simple form:

```
<form data-abide novalidate method="POST">
  <label>First name
  <input type="text" name="firstname" required> 
  </label>
  <input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>
```

I'm trying to add a new field and make Foundation check it.

```
$('<label>Last Name<input name="lastname" type="text" required></label>').insertBefore('input[type=submit]').foundation();
```

Example here:
https://jsfiddle.net/wcLmb3y9/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found it guys!!!

Just add a

```
Foundation.reInit('abide');
```

Right after the html you've included and vóila!

Hope it helps more guys!

lml

Comment: I found that in addition to this code, I had to rebind the **'forminvalid.zf.abide'** and **'formvalid.zf.abide'** (Foundation 6.4.3), like this : *$('formWithDynamicallyAddedFields').on('forminvalid.zf.abide',function(e){alert('invalid');}).on('formvalid.zf.abide',function(e){alert('valid');});*